# Can't use OnClickListener on TileView

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I'm using the project [TileView](https://github.com/moagrius/TileView)  to display big images and add markers on it, in android, it works well Except that when I put an OnClickListener on the View does not work, i use the code bellow:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener  {

TileView tileView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tileView = new TileView(this);
    tileView.setSize( 1066, 678 );

    tileView.addDetailLevel( 1.000f, "arc/tiles/arc-%col%_%row%.png", "arc/arc.png");

    tileView.setClickable(true);
    setContentView( tileView );
    tileView.setOnClickListener(this);    
}


@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

// thing to do  

}
```

what should I do so OnClickListener works

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? Does it crash? Have you set a breakpoint or log in there to see if it reaches it?

Comment: no just nothing happen when i click

Comment: small note: you can remove this bit "setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);". It gets overridden anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TileView` apparently defines a `TileViewEventListener` interface, and the `addTileViewEventListener()` method. I would suggest using those, with the interface's `onFingerDown()` and/or `onFingerUp()` methods.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get id of the view for accessing onclick

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {


    int viewId = view.getId();

    switch (viewId) {
        case R.id.button_id:
            //do smthing
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I sent a [question](https://github.com/moagrius/TileView/issues/126#issuecomment-50793019) to the owner of the library, he helped me to solve the probleme,
like oguzhand suggests, i have to use a TileViewEventListener,

the code below works well (proposed by the owner of the library TileView)

```
tileView.addTileViewEventListener( listener );
...
private TileViewEventListenerImplementation listener = new TileViewEventListenerImplementation(){
public void onTap( int x, int y ) {
    Log.d( "DEBUG", "tapped" );
}
```

}